# Android HTTP PUT Request

Tags: android

Can anyone give me a `HTTP PUT` request example code for Android?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming you want to use an HttpURLConnection, to perform an HTTP PUT you use the following:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/resource");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
    httpCon.getOutputStream());
out.write("Data you want to put");
out.close();
```

To use the HTTPPut class then try:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/resource");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPut put= new HttpPut(url);

List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", "value1"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2", "value2"));
put.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);
```

I'm pretty sure this should work though I haven't tested it :)

Comment: I think that's correct, that's how you do a POST, I've never actually tried a PUT before

Comment: is the setEntity used to pass data? As in out.write(...) in the first example? If yes, how do I pass simple string to it?

Comment: @BeRecursive: I tried the both things even its not working for me, Its giving server error code 500. I am using the HttpPu class.

Comment: Error code 500 is a server side error aka something is going wrong on the server not in this code

Comment: The second method using HttpPut does not work for me. URL is not an acceptable parameter for HttpPut.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a library like [`Android Async HTTP`](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) or [`Volley`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) that take the complexity out of networking and make it easier to handle request responses. This is how you would do it with AsyncHTTP:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("some_key", "value-1");
params.put("another_key", "value-2");

client.put(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler {
  public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response) {
    // Do something with response
  }
});
```

Comment: ```
new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Data post update success");
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Data post update failure" + statusCode + " and " + error);
//                throw error;
            }
        }
```